# Sending POST with groovy and data is already URL-encoded

Tags: http, encoding, groovy

I'm trying to send a POST using Groovy HTTPBuilder but the data I want to send is already URL-encoded so I want HTTPBuilder to POST it as is. I tried the following:

```
def validationString = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + postData
def http = new HTTPBuilder(grailsApplication.config.grails.paypal.server)
http.request(Method.POST) {
    uri.path = "/"
    body = validationString
    requestContentType = ContentType.TEXT

    response.success = { response ->
            println response.statusLine
    }
}
```

But it gives me a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate.setBody(HTTPBuilder.java:1200)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using pre-encoded form values you cannot use the default map-based content type encoder. You must specify the content type so the `EncoderRegistry` knows how to handle the body.

You may create the HttpBuilder with a content type that specifies the body is a URL-encoded string:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(url, ContentType.URLENC)
```

Or make the request passing the content type explicitly:

```
http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.URLENC) {
  // etc.
```

---

For reference, here's how I figured it out--I didn't know before I read the question.

- Looked at the `request` method's API docs to see what the closure was expected to contain. I've used `HTTPBuilder` only in passing, so I wanted to see what, specifically, the `body` "should" be, or "may" be, and if the two were different.
- The [four-arg version of the request method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/HTTPBuilder.html#request%28java.lang.Object,%20groovyx.net.http.Method,%20java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) links to the [`RequestConfigDelegate` class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/HTTPBuilder.RequestConfigDelegate.html) and said the options were discussed in its docs.
- The [`RequestConfigDelegate.setBody` method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/HTTPBuilder.RequestConfigDelegate.html#setBody%28java.lang.Object%29), which is what the `body` setter is, states the body "[...] may be of any type supported by the associated [request encoder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/EncoderRegistry.html). That is, the value of `body` will be interpreted by the encoder associated with the current [request content-type](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/HTTPBuilder.RequestConfigDelegate.html#getRequestContentType%28%29)."
- The [request encoder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/EncoderRegistry.html) link is to the `EncoderRegistry` class. It has an [`encode_form` method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/EncoderRegistry.html#encodeForm%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) taking a string and states it "assumes the String is an already-encoded POST string". Sounds good.
- The request content-type link was to an `HttpBuilder` inner class method, [`RequestConfigDelegate.getRequestContentType`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/HTTPBuilder.RequestConfigDelegate.html#getRequestContentType%28%29), which in turn had a link to the [`ContentType` enum](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/ContentType.html).
- That enum has a [`URLENC` value](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/ContentType.html#URLENC) that led me to believe it'd be the best first guess.
- I tried the [`HTTPBuilder` ctor taking a content type](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/index.html), and that worked.
- Circled back to the `request` methods and noticed there's a version also taking a content type.

I'd guess the total time was ~5-10 minutes, much shorter than it took to type up what I did. Hopefully it'll convince you, though, that finding this kind of stuff out *is* possible via the docs, in relatively short order.

IMO this is a critical skill for developers to groom, and make you look like a hero. And it can be fun.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try that out. That said, to be fair, your method also involved some non-basic source-code reverse engineering to find information that was not in the doc. It's the kind of thing I usually do, but by experience, Groovy is particularly messy with all this due to all the DSL and dynamic methods, so I tend to throw these questions like messages in a bottle while I continue searching like you did in case somebody already figured out the magic trick and can shortcut my search. In the present case, you figured it out before I did. That said, I still have to try it...

Comment: @Sebastien I didn't look at the source code at all; the steps listed above are exactly what I did/looked at. I'll update to be more explicit that I looked at the request methods docs only.